# Galera Cluster in read-write split and query cache

Tags: galera, query-cache, mariadb-10.4, maxscale

I currently have 3 MariaDB 10.4 servers, configured as a Galera cluster. In front of it, a Maxscale router to split writes (1 master) and reads (2 slaves). QC is disabled in all 3 servers.

My question is: as the servers 2 and 3 are receiving READS only, is there any (real) benefit to enable QC on those 2 servers? Like server load decreasing?

I've already tried the Maxscale cache filter out of the box, but some queries have problems with it.

Comment: If you know which queries cause problems with MaxScale, you could open a bug report on the [MariaDB Jira under the MaxScale project](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS). This would help determine if there is something that can be done to improve the situation as placing the cache closer to the client is most of the time the best solution.

Comment: Do you have a reading query performance problem you are hoping QC solves? If so it would be good to see what that is. QC is rather simplistic hence is default disabled, can gets invalidated on very table data change and suffers contention problems while searching for cached queries.

Comment: I understand what QC is, but in my case, on a master/slave setup, I would like to know if enabling QC on slaves (reads only) as any advantage or not, in a merely tuning perspective. If the drawbacks, **even in this kind of setup** are greater than the advantages, whats the point of QC being available (in MariaDB, as MySQL as dropped its support)? https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/